# How to load embedded resource into an Android Bitmap with Xamarin?

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, embedded-resource, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms application which manages some assets in the shared project by using the [embedded images feature](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images). Now I have platform specific renderers which also need to access these images.

On iOS I can simply use

```
UIImage.FromResource(typeof(CustomMap).Assembly, "my_graphic");
```

to load an embedded image and use it in an UIImageView or similar. How can the same be accomplished in Android specific code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clean and tested but you might want to create an instance of ImageLoaderSourceHandler class and call its LoadImageAsync method passing it an instance of ImageSource, context and CancellationToken (optional).
You'll end up with an instance of Android.Graphics.Bitmap.

Or if you want to bypass Forms you might want to create links to those images in Android project and use them normally. Or load a [byte stream from embedded resource](http://developer.xamarin.com/content/EmbeddedResources/)

Comment: Using the ImageLoaderSourceHandler somehow interferes with loading the other images... but https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/master/EmbeddedResources/SharedLib/ResourceLoader.cs did the trick: var stream = EmbeddedResourceLoader.GetEmbeddedResourceStream("my_graphic"); var bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(stream);

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'm doing it:

```
var key = "my_graphic";
using (var imageStream = Assembly.GetAssembly (typeof(YOURNAMESPACE.App)).GetManifestResourceStream (key))
                {
                   var bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync (imageStream);
                }
```

my embedded images are in the XamarinForms project (PCL)

Answer (score 0):

In droid renderer you can set an image to Imageview like this. While using platform specific code use images in platform's file structure. In android Include your images in Drawable folder.

```
        global::Android.Widget.ImageView imageview = new global::Android.Widget.ImageView ();
        imageview.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.my_graphic);
```

Comment: I've asked about using embedded resources on Android, not the Android Resource mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

**This might work for you.**

```
// If your class is inherited from activity or android context then use this.
var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
var img = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler().LoadImageAsync(imageSource,this);
```

or

```
// if your class is not from android context then use this.
var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
var img = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler().LoadImageAsync(imageSource,Android.App.Application.Context);
```

**Here is the full implementation**

```
private async Bitmap GetBitMap(path)
{
   var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(path);
   return await new ImageLoaderSourceHandler().LoadImageAsync(imageSource,Android.App.Application.Context);
}
```